# JQuery Availability on Maven Repositories

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, maven, webjars

I noticed that there are a few Maven plugins for Eclipse that support JavaScript development.  The problem with using these is that I cannot find any JavaScript artifacts in Maven Central Repository.  Specifically, I was looking for JQuery.

Is there a dedicated Maven repository for JavaScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Try webjars. http://www.webjars.org/

It has all the major libraries, plus it's in github, so you can fork your own versions if you really need to.

It should work well with a servlet 3 spec container with meta data scanning.  But I use https://github.com/bazaarvoice/dropwizard-webjars-resource/ to serve it explicitly, since I'm using JAX-RS (using Jersey).

Comment: Would you explain how to refer to JQuery library in jsp when using maven dependency ?

Comment: See http://www.webjars.org/documentation and if that is not clear ask a new question and link to it from a comment here.

Comment: Thank you. For those who're a bit lazy :) `<script type="text/javascript" src='webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>` just don't forget to refer to proper version folder that you use

Comment: oh thx, but why the src no need the org/ part, just start with webjars? As I see the whole path in zip is ".m2\repository\org\webjars\jquery\3.6.3\jquery-3.6.3.jar\META-INF\resources\webjars\jquery\3.6.3\"

Answer (score 6):

If your question is about repository of javascript, you can have a look at CDNs:

- Google CDN: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/ (you can just use the src link without using google's javascript)
- Microsoft CDN: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx

However, please be mindful that they do not provide a local javascript (like how Maven retrieve and store jars), thus Internet connection is necessary and there will be a network overhead.

And more, they do not manage dependencies of javascript. Dependency management of javascript is a much bigger issue in itself.

Hope I have answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on and off in my spare time on a better story for Maven and JavaScript development. You can see the results of my efforts at [jszip.org](http://jszip.org/)

Personally speaking I think there are only a few issues left to resolve:

- How to handle LESS and SASS stylesheets in dependencies
- Tidy up the code to make it more extensible
- Better documentation.

As part of the effort, I do repackage JavaScript libraries as simple `.zip` files, you can see a complete list [on central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jszip.redist%22) and you will note that [jQuery](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jszip.redist%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jquery%22) is one of them, though I probably have to pick up the 1.9.x releases when I next get a window of opertunity

Because I am packaging these as plain simple `.zip` files you don't have to use the rest of the jszip toolchain, though obviously I think it superior to just unpacking the `.zip` as part of your build with, e.g. `dependency:unpack-dependencies`

Here is an example of how to add a jszip module using its tooling:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jszip.redist</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
      <type>jszip</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jszip.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>jszip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>

  <!-- this next part assumes you want to minify all javascript for releases 
       and that your release profile used by the maven release plugin is called
       'release' (i.e. the default) -->
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jszip.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>jszip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>optimize</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: FYI I have just pushed jQuery 1.9.0 and jQuery Migrate 1.0.0 to Central... they should show up some time in the next 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is more popular for java than javascript, so you will only find a limited number of javascript libraries on the maven central repo.  JQuery is quite popular though, and several packages for it exist on maven central as you can see [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjquery).

For other javascript libraries, you can try to get maven to use [npm](https://npmjs.org/), which is a popular package management system for Node.js. There is a [plugin](https://github.com/mulesoft/npm-maven-plugin) that will allow you to download npm modules in your maven build. Here is the [jquery npm package](https://npmjs.org/package/jquery).

If that fails, you can always package the javascript libraries you need and [upload them to maven central repo](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html) yourself.